# Sending client certificates on custom ClosableHttpClient for zuul

Tags: java, spring, ssl, httpclient

I'm trying to send an X.509 client certificate with outgoing requests for zuul forwardproxy. Certificate is included in the keystore which i'm loading with `loadKeyMaterial()` on SSLContext.

Here's the code:

```java
    @Bean
    public CloseableHttpClient httpClient() throws Throwable {
        SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()
                .loadKeyMaterial(new File(keyStorePath), keyStorePass, keyStorePass, new PrivateKeyStrategy() {
                    @Override
                    public String chooseAlias(Map<String, PrivateKeyDetails> aliases, Socket socket) {
                        return alias;
                    }
                })
                .loadTrustMaterial(new File(keyStorePath), keyStorePass, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
                .build();

        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                sslcontext,
                new String[] { "TLSv1.3" },
                new String[] { "TLS_DHE_RSAWITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384" },
                SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());

        return HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
           .build();
    }
```

when i make a test request i'm getting `Received fatal alert: handshake_failure` and on the verbose logs i see the message `No X.509 certificate for client authentication, use empty Certificate message instead`. How i can make the httpClient send the certificate as X.509 client certificate?

Answer (score 3):

I had encountered simmilar problem in my case it was two part solution.

1. Import correcly certificate,

I had incorrectly created keystore:

```
keytool -importcert -keystore keystore.jks -alias client-cert -file client-cert.pem  -storepass password
```

What helped me was:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -chain -in client-cert.pem  -inkey client-key.pem  -out keystore.p12 -name client-cert -CAfile ca-cert.pem
keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore keystore.jks -srckeystore keystore.p12 -alias client-cert
```

I found this here:
https://blogs.oracle.com/jtc/installing-trusted-certificates-into-a-java-keystore

2. Problem with spring-cloud-starter-zuul 1.1.5.RELEASE. Zuul did not used my custom CloseableHttpClient, this issue was solved in https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2026 and after upgrading to 1.4.2.RELEASE this problem was fixed.